# How can the screen be adjusted such that the cursor should point to the highlighted text

Tags: java, screen

How can the screen be adjusted such that the cursor should point to the highlighted text
on maximizing/minimizing or expanding the window size in java UI

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [`java.awt.Robot`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, which can be used to move the mouse pointer using the `mouseMove(int x, int y)` method.

The it is a simply a case of obtaining the bounds of the Component containing the text and relocating the mouse to the center of the bounds; e.g.

```
// Application frame definition:
JFrame frame = ...

// Text field embedded within frame:
JTextField txtFld = ...

// Add WindowListener responsible for detecting when window state changes.
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
    // Reposition mouse over text field providing window isn't iconified.
    if (frame.getExtendedState() != JFrame.ICONIFIED) {
      Rectangle bounds = txtFld.getBounds();
      Robot.moveMouse(bounds.x / 2, bounds.y / 2);
    }
  }
});
```